# SET operations and JOIN operations

Tags: mysql

I was going through the Learning SQL 2nd Edition book. Is there any difference between the `SET` operations and the `JOIN`.Are there any situations where you would go with `SET` operations leaving `JOIN`.

Correct me if i am wrong, we can do all the things using `JOIN` what we can do with `SET`.

Comment: Are you referring to set operations like `UNION, INTERSECT`? `UNION` has a very different function than `JOIN`.

Comment: Can you give an example where you can use `SET` instead of `JOIN`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot do all the things with a `join` that you can do with the set operations.  However, if two tables have the same structure *and* have unique identifiers on each, then you can:

A `union` would be:

```
select driver.id,
       coalesce(t1.col1, t2.col1) as col1,
       . . .  -- repeat this for all columns
from (select distinct coalesce(t1.id, t2.id) as id
      from ((select id
             from t1
            ) full outer join
            (select id
             from t2
            )
           )
     ) driver left outer join
     t1
     on t1.id = driver.id left outer join
     t2
     on t2.id = driver.id
```

The `except` and `intersect` can be approached in the same way, but putting conditions on the `full outer join` in the driver table.

In fact, you can extend this idea to not require a unique id, just assuming that the rows are unique in each table.  In that case, the joins are more complicated, because you have to include all columns, and also take into account NULL values in the columns.

That said, the `set` operations have several advantages:

1. They are more readable.  You and everyone else would probably agree that `union` and `union all` are much more readable than the above queries.
2. The SQL engine understands the set operations, so they are typically going to be more efficient.
3. It is easy to make a subtle error in the more complicated SQL statement that would radically change the results.  For instance, changing the 'full outer join' in the driver table above into 'inner join' is the difference between `union` and `intersect`.

Answer (score 3):

Set operations are `UNION` , `INTERSECT` and `EXCEPT`. They are used for doing set operations on relations having **same schema**. For example: let `R1` and `R2` be of the following schema:

```
R1 (A,B,C)
R2 (A,B,C)
```

- R1 `UNION` R2 = union of all rows in `R1` and `R2`.
- R1 `INTERSECT` R2 = the common rows in both `R1` and `R2`.
- R1 `EXCEPT` R2 = All rows from `R1` that do not exist in `R2`.

Note that we use set operations on **same schema** relations, but we can use join operations on different schema relations which schema of the result is the union of both schemas. (Usually we use join operations for joining two or more tables.)